# Custom Siri Intents are not working in iOS 12.2, which is working good in 12.01

Tags: ios, iphone, siri, sirikit

In iOS 12.2, Siri short cuts stoped working.

override func handler is not getting called.

Unable to find any Siri related change in iOS release notes. Any one else facing same issue ?

Siri Short cuts are getting added. But only answer I got from Siri is "Sorry Something went wrong in the app". **The issue is occurring only in 12.2 device, any clue on this.**